# Line breaks and alignment in table cells with math environment

Tags: tables, math-mode, alignment, line, cell

I am trying to build a table which has math environments and forced line breaks. I've found some solutions that come close to what I desire. Effectively, I am working on something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|c}|}
\hline
$\pmb{\alpha}$ & $\begin{aligned}[t] & \pmb{\beta} \\ & \textbf{Possible}\end{aligned}$ & $\begin{aligned}[t]&\pmb{\gamma} \\ & \textbf{Not Possible}\end{aligned}$ & \textbf{Stuff} $\equiv \frac{\pmb{\delta}}{\mu}$ \\

\hline

\textbf{1}  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\textbf{2} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives me a table that looks like this:
[image]

However, if it is possible, I would like to align the upper left cell and the upper right cell vertically. I recognize that my current method does not allow this because of nature of the math alignment function. I would greatly welcome any other recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{|c}|}
\hline
$\pmb{\alpha}$ & 
$\pmb{\beta}$ & $\pmb{\gamma}$ &
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Stuff} $\displaystyle\equiv \frac{\pmb{\delta}}{\mu}$ }
 \\ & \textbf{Possible}& \textbf{Not Possible} & \\
\hline
\textbf{1}  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\textbf{2} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You already loaded `makecell`, why not use it? `makecell` will automatically center cell contents vertically. Also use `bm` instead of `pmb` to bold-face Greek characters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|*4{c|}}
\hline
\makecell{$\bm\alpha$} & \makecell{$\bm\beta$\\\textbf{Possible}} & \makecell{$\bm\gamma$\\\textbf{Not Possible}} & \textbf{Stuff} $\equiv \frac{\bm\delta}{\mu}$ \\ \hline
\textbf{1}  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\textbf{2}  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]